# Azure sitesroot does not contain all deployed files

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I'm deploying a web role to Azure using VS 2013. I added a `Contents` element to my `.csdef` file to deploy extra files that are not included in the Azure deployment package like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="..." xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2014-06.2.4">
  <WebRole name="..." vmsize="Small">
    <!-- snip -->

    <Contents>
      <Content destination="bin/">
        <SourceDirectory path="C:\...\bin"/>
      </Content>
    </Contents>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

When the package is deployed, I can see the extra files being put in the `approot` folder on the instance's `F:` drive. However, these files are never deployed to the `sitesroot\0` folder, from which the web role seems to run. Because these extra files are assemblies that are to be loaded dynamically, I would like them to be together with the application's other assemblies.

Is this behavior intentional or am I doing something wrong? There doesn't seem to be much information about this online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the Content element in the end, but with a different destination path, pointing to the sitesroot folder. It's a bit of a hack, but at least it works without diving into MSBuild or manual packaging of the deployment.

```xml
<ServiceDefinition name="..." xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2014-06.2.4">
  <WebRole name="..." vmsize="Small">
    <!-- snip -->

    <Contents>
      <Content destination="..\sitesroot\0\bin">
        <SourceDirectory path="C:\...\bin" />
      </Content>
    </Contents>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is [as per the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg557553.aspx#Contents) which states that the deployed location is relative to the Role's APPROOT (the behaviour you are seeing).

If you want them deployed into your site's bin folder you need to package them as part of your Visual Studio solution.

Comment: I understand that the behaviour is as described in the documentation. I just thought these folders would be synchronised in some way. I cannot add these files to the solution (not in a 'reference assembly and Copy Local' kind of way anyway). How would one do this?

Comment: You could manually include them using a post build step by ensuring they are copied to the right folder in the solution so that cspack (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg433133.aspx) packages them into your deployment package.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a DLL to your root directory of a project (Add -> Existing Item). If you take that DLL and change the `Build Action` set to `Content` and the `Copy to Output Directory` set to `Copy Always` then I think this will make sure that the DLL ends up being in your `BIN` folder, or equiv.

---

An example of what I've done in the past:
Two projects in a Solution named:

- `DependenciesProject` (Class Library)
- `WebProject` (MVC App)

I had a need where some specific DLLs that needed to be bundled into the compiled package were included but the specific DLL that would be used would change based on my compiled targets (x64 vs x86). The solution we chose to go with was to have the `DependenciesProject` do what I described for you to do above and we modified the `.csproj` file to change the path to these native DLLs based on the target specified at compile-time (we disabled `Any CPU`).

So the `DependenciesProject` had these DLLs in the root directory (with that `.csproj` having some tweaks for dynamic paths to the DLLs that existed in our Nuget `packages` folder) and the DLLs in the Solution Explorer had the `Build Action` set to `Content` and the `Copy to Output Directory` set to `Copy Always`. This means whenever a `DependenciesProject.dll` file was compiled, it would move the other DLLs into the same output folder as that .DLL file.

Now `WebProject` project would have a Project Reference to `DependenciesProject`. This means every time I try to compile `WebProject`, it will first compile `DependenciesProject` and then copy its output folder into the `WebProject`'s output folder.

The end result: `DependenciesProject.dll` as well as `MySpecial.dll` existed with my web application every time I needed it.

---

Does this help?